# Can I run my rake jobs:work in the same docker container as I run my rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

My docker compose file

```
 web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
      - db-test
    depends_on:
      - db
      - db-test
```

Then I usually login into the container with

```
docker-compose exec web bash
```

and then run

```
rake jobs:work
```

Is it possible to run both things and skip the last step?

Comment: Would changing command to `bash -c "bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 && rake jobs:work" ` work for you?

Comment: I tried and then changed it to a single &. That worked. Is that because  a double is waiting for the first process to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two long-running tasks you want to do on the same code base, you can run two separate containers off the same image.  In Docker Compose syntax that would look like

```
version: '3'
services:
  db: { ... }
  db-test: { ... }
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - db-test
  worker:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rake jobs:work
    depends_on:
      - db
      - db-test
```

Running multiple tasks in one container is kind of tricky and isn't usually recommended.  The form you arrived on in comments, for example, launches the Rails server as a background task, and then makes the worker the main container process; if for some reason the main Rails application dies, Docker won't notice this, and if the worker dies, it will take the Rails application with it.